# What is this CSS focus feature called?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://demo.thedevelovers.com/dashboard/kingboard-v1.1/

In the link above, if you click on the eye icon on the dashboard's top tool bar in the upper right, the dashboard div gets focused. What is this called? I'm sure it's using CSS?

Comment: It might be using a little bit of CSS, but most of that is JavaScript.

Comment: I don't see an eye icon on the toolbar.

Comment: It's pretty small, but it's on the toolbar of where the dashboard sits, not on the main toolbar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ahh I think I found it. It's a variation of Bootstrap Tour (http://bootstraptour.com/)

If you do the tour, you'll see that one part of the tour will focus on a div. The part that does the focus is called `backdrop`

Answer (score 1):

> What is this called?

That dashboard uses a clever take on [modal windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window). While it certainly makes use of CSS for styling the change, it's not a single CSS rule, as there are a number of interactions taking place which are controlled by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
input:focus
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

It is part of the selector for :focus apart of css